# How to de-structure nested props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I started learning React js and I reached to the topic of destructuring props. Normally what we do is we destructure props and then use the attributes just like below code in Greet component

```
import React from "react";
const Greet = props => {
  const { name, heroName } = props; //here I destructured it
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        Hello {name} a.k.a {heroName}
      </h1>{" "}
      // and then use simply name and heroName
    </div>
  );
};
export default Greet;
```

And here is my App component

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import Greet from "./components/Greet";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Greet name="kaptan" heroName=" ek" />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

The above code works fine then I moved further and make a Person and a NameList component Below is my NameList component

```
import React from "react";
import Person from "./Person";
function NameList() {
  const persons = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "kaptan",
      age: 30,
      skill: "react"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "rinku",
      age: 29,
      skill: "java"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "ankit",
      age: 39,
      skill: "vue"
    }
  ];
  const personsList = persons.map(person => <Person person={person} />);
  return <div>{personsList}</div>;
}
export default NameList;
```

And here is my Person component

```
import React from "react";
const Person = ({ person }) => {
  // here i need to destructure person object
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>
        I am {person.name},My age is {person.age},I know {person.skill}
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Person;
```

So my question is that why in Person component I cant do destructure as I did in Greet component

like this way

```
import React from "react";
const Person = props => {
  const { name, age, skill } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>
        I am {name},My age is {age},I know {skill}
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Person;
```

It doesn't give me correct output Why?

Comment: What is the output that you get, because I can't see anything wrong with your code. I created a codesandbox with your code and it works so I don't know that the problem is.

https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-fermi-5qhro?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 24):

You can use [nested destructuring](https://davidwalsh.name/nested-destructuring) to get `person` properties:

```
const { person: { name, age, skill } } = props;
```

Nested destructuring is used here because `props` has this structure:

```
{
  person: {
    name: ...,
    age: ...,
    skill: ...
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can just get `person` from `props` and then use its properties, similar to what you initially wrote:

```
const { person } = props;

return (
  <div>
     <h2>I am {person.name},My age is {person.age},I know {person.skill} </h2>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: You don't "need" to do that. What he does is perfectly correct. Just destructure the person from the props and use the dot to get that property from the object.

Comment: thanks but what is the reason for doing nested destructuring

Comment: @KaptanBhardwaj I edited my answer to explain a bit better why nested destructuting can be used here.

Answer (score 1):

`Greet` component receives `name`, `heroName` as props from the parent, so you can destructure it like you did.

`<Greet name="kaptan" heroName=" ek"/>`

But the `Person` component receives `person` as a prop and that contains the properties `name`, `age`, `skill`, etc. So you can't directly destructure it.
You have to destructure the `person` prop

`<Person person ={person}/>`

Comment: Yeah you can directly do it.

Comment: @zixuan I meant in the way that OP is using in his `Greet` component

Answer (score 1):

You can either destructure the people and get their properties or do nested destructuring. Nested destructuring is easier because if you had more properties, then it would take more lines of code to get each of the properties.