# React, how to pass known properties and props.children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Question on how to pass properties into React methods. Probably a very easy question asked before but since I don't know how to articulate it properly, do bear with me and feel free to point me to the duplicate.

I'd like to use some known properties and prop.children of a React component at the same time, how do I pass them into my React methods?

For example, I know to pass a known property into React method component we do this:

```js
export const SomeComponent = ({prop1, prop2}) =>{ ... do something with prop1 and prop2 }
```

And the to use prop.children we need to do this:

```js
export const SomeComponent = (props) =>{ ... then some tags wrapping {props.children}... }
```

And now I have a function that I need both prop1 and prop2 and also the props.children. How should I construct the syntax to realize this need?

i.e. essentially using it as:

```js
<SomeComponent prop1={value1} prop2={value2}>
   <NestedComponent />
</SomeComponent>
```

Comment: you are getting prop1 and prop 2 after destructuring props. Prop1 and prop2 you can get with props also. Try props.Prop1. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60589914/destructuring-props-in-react

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const MyComp = props => {
  const {prop1, children} = props;
  // do something with props
  // do something with prop1
  // do something with children
  return (<div>{children}</div>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `({prop1, prop2})` syntax is a destructuring assignment introduced in ES6.
Actually what the function get is an object containing keys `prop1`, `prop2`, like this

```
{
  prop1: ...,
  prop2: ...,
  ...,
}
```

You can read this for more detail: [Unpacking fields from objects passed as a function parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_a_function_parameter).

Hence, when passing both prop1, prop2, and children, you can use either syntax below:

- With destructuring assignment:

  ```js
  export const SomeComponent = ({prop1, prop2, children}) => {
    ... do something with prop1, prop2, and children 
  }
  ```
- Without destructuring assignment:

  ```js
  export const SomeComponent = (props) => {
    ... do something with props.prop1, props.prop2, and props.children 
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this -

```
<SomeComponent  prop1={} prop2={}>
  <div> test </div>
</SomeComponent>

 export const SomeComponent = (props) =>{ ...access the prop1 as props.prop1 and prop2 
 as props.prop2 and children like props.children }
```